# How to handle 2 same Option Menus with one distinguish menu item

Tags: android, optionmenu

ive got 2 activities with option menus. the option menus exists of 4 menu items. 3 of them (option1, option2 and option3) exist in both option menus. the option menus distinguish between the 4th menu item (option4 in activity1 and option5 in activity2).

Is there in Android an opportunity to outsource the 3 same options in - for example a OptionMenuHelper class - and access it from the 2 activities so that i dont have to implement 2 times exactly the same methods in onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem)?

thanks in advice

pebbles

---

1st Update

example:

I want to outsource exportAsCSV() so i can access it from my 2 activities

```
 @Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {  

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case ...

        case R.id.om_export:
            exportAsCSV();                
            return true;
        case ...
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

and the exportAsCSV includse a cursor which gets data from a Content Provider over getContentResolver. and the ContentResolver cant be static :/

```
private void exportAsCSV() {

   ...

   Cursor cursor = getContentResolver().query(MyQueries.CONTENT_URI_ALL,
            new String[]{Column1, Column2},
            "", null, Column1);

   ....
}
```

---

2nd Update

Okay I solved it:

```
public class MenuHelper {

    Context context;

    public ExportHelper(Context con) {
        context=con;
    }


    public void exportAsCSV() {

    ...

    Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(MyQueries.CONTENT_URI_ALL,
        new String[]{Column1, Column2},
        "", null, Column1);

    ...

    }
}
```

Well this way isnt static (what was my intention) but its working. Now i can access it from every activity i want by creating an object...

Thank you anyway

(If u know a solution how to do that in static, let me know ;) )

greets

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't really see the advantage of that, except that you don't want to have boilerplate code. You absolutely can write an static helper method, that does inflation of the menu.xml.

I would just write one menu.xml and decide in `onCreateOptionsMenu()`of the two activities which items are to be shown. It's not that much code. For example like this:

```
@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu ( Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater ) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.shared_menu, menu);

    MenuItem item5 = menu.findItem(R.id.item_5);

    // hide in activity 2
    if(item5 != null)
        item5.setVisible(false);

    // static helper call
    MenuHelper.initActiviyMenu(this, menu, inflater);
}

...

public class MenuHelper {
    public static void initActivity( Activity activity, Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater ){
         inflater.inflate(R.menu.shared_menu, menu);

         if(activity instanceof ActivityA){
             // do stuff, hide items, content provider 
         }
         if(activity instanceof ActivityB){
             // do stuff, hide items, content provider 
         }
    }


}
```

Comment: ahh thank you... never thought about the visibilty :) - but how do i write a static helper methode (wich i can in in both onCreateOptionsMenu() - Methods)? I got a cursor in there who uses getContentResolver() and this cant be static :/

Comment: I added an example for your static helper. You could do it like this and maybe also deal with your contentProvider there. You have to pass the activity as context.

Comment: wow sorry, i messed up there something. Guess i was kinda tired when i wrote my last message. I ment how can i use the MenuHelper class in the onItemSelected-Method? i ve attached an example